# ScrollBar and Caret Position screwed up after assigning lines in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

My issue is that when I write over the Lines attribute of a RichTextBox the cursor flies to the top of the text box, and sticks there. I cannot move it at all, no arrow keys or mouse work. Here is my code,

Code: (This is called when the caret changes position without typing) *arrow keys or mouse click*

```
private void UpdateVisibleLines()
{

    string[] tmpArr = this.Lines;
    if (this.LineCount > 5)
    {
        tmpArr[3] = "blah";
    }
    this.Lines = tmpArr;
}
```

I was reading and figured out myself also that I cannot do this to assign new strings for each line in a text box

```
rtb.Lines[i] = "Blah";
```

I have to make a tmp array and then assign rtb.Lines to that. I figure my problem is when I assign the rtb's text to be the new array. But I cannot figure out why the caret goes the the top of the text, and then stays there...

Comment: It sounds like your method is getting called repeatedly.

Comment: Yeah, as I said in the OP I think it is too. But I cannot figure out why...

Comment: Where are you calling `UpdateVisibleLines()` from?  Right mouse click the method and select "Find All References".  Also, to send someone a Stack Overflow notification in comments, use the @ sign followed by the user name.

Comment: I am calling it in, OnVScroll overridden method.